# onLongPress is not working same as onClick

Tags: react-native, use-state, usecallback

I am passing **onLongPress** on a Component that has the same function as **onClick**. I have used `useState` for both. When I long press the item it opens the menu but again if I Long press the menu stays open.

```js
  
     const resetNavItems = () => {
            setIsFirstComponentOpen(false);
            setIsSecondComponentOpen(false); 
        }

    const onClickItem = useCallback(index => {
        resetNavItems();
        
        if (index === 2) {
            setIsFirstComponentOpen(!FirstComponentOpen);    
        } else if (index === 3) { 
            setIsSecondComponentOpen(!SecondComponentOpen);    
        }
    });

    <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={onClickItem} />
```

Comment: Dont nuke the question, make an edit to reflect what you've found.

Answer (score 0):

Your opposite of `!isMembersTrayOpen` and `!isMoreTrayOpen` will always be **true** because your `resetNavItems` is called to always set it to **false**. You could try:

```
const [FirstComponentOpen, setIsFirstComponentOpen] = useState(false)
const [SecondComponentOpen, setIsSecondComponentOpen] = useState(false)

const onClickItem = useCallback(index => {
  index === 2 ? setIsFirstComponentOpen(true) : setIsFirstComponentOpen(false)
  index === 3 ? setIsSecondComponentOpen(true) : setIsSecondComponentOpen(false)
})

<TouchableOpacity onLongPress={onClickItem} />
```

if you remove `resetNavItems` then your original conditions would likely work:

```
const onClickItem = useCallback(index => {
  if (index === 2) setIsFirstComponentOpen(!FirstComponentOpen);    
  if (index === 3) setIsSecondComponentOpen(!SecondComponentOpen);    
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that , still no changes . I got your point  but I don't know what else is missing here

Comment: can you make a codesandbox so I can replicate the issue?

Comment: I kind of fixed it by removing resetNavItems();